# Vim: PHP debug plugin watch window fails to work because of filetype plugin on setting

Tags: debugging, vim, xdebug

I am giving Vim [xdebug plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2508) a try, but when I put cursor on a variable I would like to inspect, press <kbd>F12</kbd>, it fails to show the contents in Watch window, just types:

```
/*{{{1*/ => property_get: filterItems
```

and enters Insert mode instead of showing the property contents.

I figured out it happens when `filetype plugin on` is set. Commenting this out makes it work well. Why is that happening? Maybe `filetype plugin on` directive enables some other settings which break the debugger?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around:

```
function DebugOn()                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    filetype plugin off
    :python debugger_run()                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
endfunction                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
map <Leader>dd :call DebugOn()<cr>                                                                                                                                                                                                           

function DebugOff()                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    :python debugger_quit()                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    filetype plugin on
endfunction                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
map <Leader>dq :call DebugOff()<cr>
```

So everytime before I run the debugger I set filetype plugin off, and set it back on when I quit debugging. This seems to solve my problem.